# html dynamic table print to php

Tags: php, html

I need some help...

I've created a form with a dynamic table in it. I would like to learn how to pass it through php and echo/print it to a php page to save the page as pdf.

I am stuck on this part. I've looked everywhere for some answers and I cant seem to be finding anything.

```
<form action="display_form.php" method="POST">
<table id="dataTable" width="auto" style="margin:-4px 0 0 0;" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20px;"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
        <td><INPUT type="text" name="step" style="width:160px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="step" required/></td>
        <td><INPUT type="text" name="url" style="width:62px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="url" required/></td>
        <td><INPUT type="text" name="process" style="width:63px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="process" required/></td>
        <td>
            <SELECT name="pass-fail" style="width:100px;">
                <OPTION value="Pass">one</OPTION>
                <OPTION value="Fail">two</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        </td>
        <td><INPUT type="text" name="comment" style="width:190px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Comment" required/></td>
</table>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

I have called the php file `display_form.php` where I would like to display the dynamic table data in the. The function to save it as a pdf is in there as well. But I am mainly after the printing of the form to the php file. I am having no luck there at all!

I'm not worried on posting the table to mysql. I have other ways where i don't need it in mysql

I would really appreciate the help

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'printing of the form to the php file'?

Comment: The print is echoing the data entered in the html to the php file to then be saved as a pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things

- you have not closed `tr`

Next

Make all input elements as array. Then you can fetch them in your php file

```
 <td style="width:20px;"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]" /></td>
    <td><INPUT type="text" name="step[]" style="width:160px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="step" required/></td>
    <td><INPUT type="text" name="url[]" style="width:62px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="url" required/></td>
    <td><INPUT type="text" name="process[]" style="width:63px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="process" required/></td>
    <td>
        <SELECT name="pass-fail[]" style="width:100px;">
            <OPTION value="Pass">one</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="Fail">two</OPTION>
        </SELECT>
    </td>
    <td><INPUT type="text" name="comment[]" style="width:190px;" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Comment" required/></td>
```

In your php file, use foreach loop to get all the values.

```
  $i = 0;
    $array = array();
    foreach ($_POST['step'] as $row) {
        $array[$i]['step'] = $row;
        $array[$i]['chk'] = isset($_POST['ckh'][$i]) ? 1 : 0;
        $array[$i]['url'] = $_POST['url'][$i];
        $i++;
        //...//so on
    }

    print_R($array);
```

Comment: GUYS!!! You are geniuses!!!!! It is working. The looping was indeed the issue. i re-looked into the process in my display_form.php file and changed the looping as well as my element. I will add it to the page now to show you. Thank you Niranjan N Raju, alexandre, vivek s vamja

Comment: post to mysql?? u mean inserting data to mysql??

Comment: use that for loop in my answer for your input values. then use `insert batch` to insert the code.

Comment: I tried but the insert is inserting into separate rows. i want all the answers to be in one row where the user's row is

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the javascript addRow function should add another tr-row in the table (the closing  is missing by the way).
Now you have in every table row inputs with the same names. That won't work.

You need to say, that they are arrays, to access them via $_POST['step'][0] and so on.
Just give them name="step[]" and the form will automatically count the index for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use name='step[]',name='url[]',name='process[]' as input type for your add row functionality, 
Now when you submit form you are getting array then store that array as below.

```
$step = $_REQUEST['step']; 
$url = $_REQUEST['url']; 
$process = $_REQUEST['process'];
```

Now use foreach loop.

```
foreach($step as $key => $row){
    echo $step[$key];
    echo $url[$key];
    echo $process[$key];
}
```

Now format your data in html then generate pdf as per below link.

http://phptopdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
$step = $_REQUEST['step'];
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
$process = $_REQUEST['process'];
$pass_fail = $_REQUEST['pass-fail'];
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

foreach ($step as $key => $row) {
    {
        ?>
        <table id="dataTable" width="auto" style="margin:-4px 0 0 0;" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
                <td><INPUT type="text" name="step[]" style="width:160px;" value="<?php echo $step[$key]; ?>"/></td>
                <td><INPUT type="text" name="url[]" style="width:62px;" value="<?php echo $url[$key]; ?>"/></td>
                <td><INPUT type="text" name="process[]" style="width:63px;" value="<?php echo $process[$key]; ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td><input name="pass-fail[]" style="width:100px;" value="<?php echo $pass_fail[$key]; ?>"/></td>
                <td><INPUT type="text" name="comment[]" style="width:190px;" value="<?php echo $comment[$key]; ?>"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php }
}
```

}

Working just fine now!!

[here the table is displaying correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aglk.jpg)